# JMeter order of samples with Redis Data

Tags: redis, jmeter

I am using Redis Data Set as a data source in my JMeter tests. I have configured the redis key with a value I retrieve from a JSR223 sampler.

Below are my test samplers.

[image]

in the bove JSR223 sampler I retrieve a previous value ${operator} and put in to properties.

Then in the next sampler ,

[image]

I reuse the value as ${__P(operator)}.

The issue with this is ,it doesn't look like JSR233 sampler is running before jp@gc RedisDataset. so the script fails like below.

```
Stop Thread seen for thread XXXXXX 1-1, reason: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of Redis data detected, thread will exit
```

If I run the script once commenting the Redis data set sampler, and run on a second run with enabling it, the value can be seen, as the value have been stored in the Jmeter memory, this way it was evident that Redis data set runs before JSR223 sampler. I can not move JSR 233 sampler out of the test fragment to a much higher level as I need to run it within the test fragment.

Is there a location which defines these order of executions with Redis samplers ?
Or is there a way to define the order in Jmeter so that JSR223 will run before Redis sampler?

===================================
UPDATE 1

After @Dmitri-t s reply, I have updated the project as follows .
[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) chapter of JMeter User Manual:

```
0. Configuration elements
1. Pre-Processors
2. Timers
3. Sampler
4. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)
```

[Redis Data Set](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-redis-data-set-an-introduction) is a Configuration Element therefore it will be executed **prior to anything else**.

The only way you can make this `operator` property dynamic is [overriding it via -J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Joperator=something -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Comment: Thanks @Dimitry, I have moved the JSR223 Sampler to the higher level ( Even though I said I cant above, I realized no harm doing that). Now my ${operatpr} variable is filled with a value before executing the jp@gc - Redis Data Set. But still I do not get any value for the rediskey name. I put the key name in to a pros in the JSR `props.put("COMMANDFILE","RDM_ENGTEST_${operator}_Commands");
System.out.println("Command File: [" + props.get("COMMANDFILE") + "]");` and then try to refer the value at RedisKey field as `${COMMANDFILE}`, which didnt gave me the right value. I even tried vars,

Comment: I don't think it really helped, if you restart your test you will run into the same problem

Comment: yes, you are right. Bottom line how can I get my Redis key parameterized ? So far I have files with the pattern `filename_ABC_commands.txt` where ABC is `operator`. I was able to resolve a `operator` at Thread Group before going down to Module Controller. But that value seems to be not able to refer at the configuration element.

Comment: what is Joperator value in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I got That working in the following way

```
TestPlan
|--Thread group
  |--Module Controller -1
  |  |--CSV Data Set Config - to load operator name(this is going to be reused in other thread groups)      
  |--Module Controller -2
     |--JSR233 Sampler - To read a second level file with ${operator} in its name
     |--For Each Controller - to read through the second level file
     |  |--User Defined Variables  - to split the line from the second level file in to variables
     |--HTTP Request - Action sampler with ${operator} and other variables
```

Ref : [Iterating over a csv file](https://hellotestworld.com/2015/12/30/iterating-over-a-csv-file-in-jmeter/)